# Google AdSense Anchor/overlay ads should not hide fixed div at the bottom of my page

Tags: html, css, adsense, adsense-anchor-ads

I have a fixed positioned div at bottom of my webpage.
Issue is when google AdSense **Page-level ad** is enable and google serves **Anchor/overlay ads**, it also hides my fixed positioned div.

Anchor/overlay ads : Mobile ads that stick to the edge of the user’s screen and are easily dismissable.

Comment: How did you solve this/